# Import/Export name collision resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, ecmascript-next

Testing in Node JS the following modules layout, looks like local exported definitions always replace external exported in case of name collision (see f1 in B.js).

## A.js

```
export const f1 = 'A'
```

## B.js

```
export * from './A.js'
export const f1 = 'B'
```

## C.js

```
import * as A from './A.js'
import * as B from './B.js'
console.log(A.f1)
console.log(B.f1)
```

```
> node C.js
// A
// B
```

Is this a rule? I have not found something about how to manage this in Ecmascript specs.

Does import/export order matter?

Do you see this as a reliable method for extending a module overloading functions and/or adding new ones?

Comment: Local exports have priority. That's actually [standardized in the spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-getexportednames).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a rule? I have not found something about how to manage this in Ecmascript specs.

Yes, Local exports have priority. Which is, in fact, [standardized in the spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-getexportednames):

5. For each ExportEntry Record *e* in *module*.[[LocalExportEntries]], do 
   a. [Assert](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-algorithm-conventions): *module* provides the direct binding for this export. 
   b. Append *e*.[[ExportName]] to *exportedNames*.
6. For each ExportEntry Record *e* in *module*.[[IndirectExportEntries]], do 
   a. [Assert](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-algorithm-conventions): *module* imports a specific binding for this export. 
   b. Append *e*.[[ExportName]] to *exportedNames*.

---

Specifically the `starExport` in your case is part of:

```
For each ExportEntry Record e in module.[[StarExportEntries]], do
    (...)
    c. Let starNames be requestedModule.GetExportedNames(exportStarSet).
    d. For each element n of starNames, do
        i. If SameValue(n, "default") is false, then
            1. If n is not an element of exportedNames, then
                a. Append n to exportedNames.
```

---

So, to answer your second question:

> Do you see this as a reliable method for extending a module overloading functions and/or adding new ones?

Yes, it's reliable because it's specified in the standard.

Comment: The `[[IndirectExportEntries]]` are export entries of the form `export * as Id from 'module'`. The export clause op uses is different and ends up being part of the `[[StarExportEntries]]`. But you are right in this case, it does give priority to the local exports.

Comment: @MinusFour Yes, you are right. Thank you! Updated the answer